# Criar um novo tema para o StackExchange?

Tags: debate

Vi que o StackExchange em inglês tem diversos temas: matemática, ciência, religião, idiomas, etc.

No Brasil tem o StackOverflow para programação (não sei se tem outros temas).

O que quero saber é: Como é criado um "Stack Overflow"? A gente pode criar um sobre um tema específico?

Comment: Só em inglês, por enquanto. Já fizemos uma proposta para o Super User em português, mas o processo foi suspenso. Mais detalhes em [Super User em Português - Por que o projeto foi fechado?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2543/70) e [Super User em Português - Já era no Area 51](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2482/70).

Comment: Também foi tentada uma [comunidade de matemática em português](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3867/132) e [uma de arduino](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3817/132) - Também não foram histórias com final feliz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isto é feito no [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Há um processo que a proposta deve passar para se transformar em site. Não é algo simples, precisa certeza que o site terá tração.

Há alguma [perguntas sobre o assunto aqui no nosso meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=area%2051).

[O SOpt passou pelo processo](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese).

Comment: A proposta do SOPT foi sua?

Comment: @diegofm hoje que você descobriu? :)

Comment: só colocando mais um link na listinha (para curiosos): [anúncio do Stack Overflow em português no blog da SE](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/ola-mundo-announcing-stack-overflow-in-portuguese/).